# How to convert German plural nouns to singular in Python?

Tags: python

I'm searching for an algorithm, which converts German plural nouns to singular. Any idea is welcome.

Comment: You could try to implement [these rules](http://www.babelnation.com/german/courses/01_07_3.html).

Answer (score 5):

Converting plural to singular and back is a *difficult* task in any language. Like with most languages, there are both [general rules and exceptions](http://www.babelnation.com/german/courses/01_07_3.html) in German, that make creating a straightforward computer algorithm tricky.

To do it properly, you'd have to use the [`nltk` library](http://nltk.org/) (the Natural Language Toolkit). This is *not* something for the faint of heart.

If you do want to go this route, O'Reilly published an excellent book on the library, now [available for free online](http://nltk.org/book/).

Answer (score 0):

You can start by examining [this example](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch02.html#code-plural) from nltk - Natural Language Toolkit.

*PS*
You can also check out [inflect](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/inflect), it does exactly what you are looking for but for English words. If you want to create something that does that for German you'd better look at how they did it in `inflect` instead of re-inventing the wheel.